# UK Family visas: can I apply as a parent if my baby is born in UK and partner is UK citizen?

Tags: united-kingdom, visa, family

My partner (British) and I (Canadian) are currently living in the UK and just had a baby. I'm currently working on a Tier 2 (General) visa (I was sponsored by the company) but am strongly considering leaving for various reasons.

To greatly facilitate the job search process I'm considering applying for the ["Family visas (Apply as a parent)](https://www.gov.uk/uk-family-visa/parent) but I'd like to be 100% sure we'll meet all the criteria before applying.

☑️ Child is under 18 and a British citizen
☑️ We are in a share parental responsibility and my partner is a British citizen
☑️ have a good knowledge of English 
☑️ I already have my Biometric residence permits
☑️ I meet the [income requirements](https://www.gov.uk/uk-family-visa/proof-income)

Am I missing anything else?
For those having applied before or knowing the process, how long does it takes to get the visa if approved? And finally can I apply for it despite currently being on another visa?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Am I missing anything else?

Yes:

> If you’re eligible to [apply as a partner](https://www.gov.uk/uk-family-visa/partner-spouse), you must do that instead of applying as a parent.

Therefore, a successful application for a parent visa should include evidence that you and your partner do not meet the criteria for a partner visa.  The fact that you and your partner just had a baby suggests that you do meet those criteria, unless you and your partner have been together for less than two years.

You also ask:

> How long does it takes to get the visa if approved?

Unfortunately, I do not know.

> Can I apply for it despite currently being on another visa?

Yes.  Note that one of the options is to apply "in the UK."  In order to be in the UK legally, you have to be "on another visa"; this implies that you can apply despite being on another visa.

Comment: Great answer, thanks for pointing that out. I will start the process to apply as a partner instead.

Comment: @FrankParent you're welcome.  Are you going to change your name now?  Good luck with the application.